# how many threads does nvidia GTS 450 has

Tags: cuda

Dear friends:
    i am want to study the CUDA programming, i bought a Nvidia GTS 450 PCI_E car. it has 192 SMs, then how many threads does it has. 192 threads? or 192*512 threads?
  Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specs](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/product-geforce-gts-450-uk.html), your device has 192 "processor cores" - these are **not** the same as SMs. In CUDA, a SM is a multiprocessor that executes multiple threads in lockstep (8 for the 1.3 family of devices, more for later devices).

As shoosh pointed out, the number of threads used is a function of your kernel invocation.

Typically to get good performance in CUDA, you should run many more threads than you have CUDA processor cores - this is to hide the latency of your global memory accesses.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!  does it has a up limit for the maxmimum of threads that i could invoked.

Comment: The maximum number of threads you can execute is the product of the maximum number of threads per block, and the maximum grid size. You should check out the CUDA programming guide - it will tell you the values.

Answer (score 2):

in CUDA the term `threads` refers to the a property of a specific kernel invocation, not of a property of the hardware.
For instance in this CUDA invocation:

```
someFunction<<<2,32>>>(1,2,3);
```

you have 32 threads in 2 blocks so 64 threads in total.
The hardware schedules threads to processors automatically.

Comment: I think he's asking for the maximum number of threads possible. Considering at each block allows 512 threads at most, he wonders if he's correct that his GPU can run 192*512 threads at once.