# How many threads can a Nvidia GPU launch?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

How many threads can a Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB GPU launch?
For example:
kernel<<<1,32>>>(args); can launch 32 threads.
So what is the maximum number of threads possible?
I am aware of this post [how many threads does nvidia GTS 450 has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861244/how-many-threads-does-nvidia-gts-450-has)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question may often arise from a misunderstanding of GPU execution behavior.  However the limits according to the prompt you have given:

> For example: kernel<<<1,32>>>(args); can launch 32 threads.

do not vary across GPUs supported by recent CUDA toolkits (i.e. GPUs of compute capability 3.0 through 8.6, which includes your GTX 1050).  These limits are given in [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications-feature-support-per-compute-capability) as well as via runtime queries such as demonstrated by the `deviceQuery` sample code.

These limits are that a threadblock (the second kernel launch configuration parameter) is limited to 1024 threads *total*, which is the product of the 3 dimensions, x,y,z, and each of those dimensions have individual limits:

```
                    x      y     z
threadblock      1024   1024    64
       grid    2^31-1  65535 65535
```

and likewise, as indicated above, the grid (the first kernel launch configuration parameter) has individual limits on each dimension, but no limit on the product.

The maximum number of threads that is possible to be specified in a kernel launch currently is therefore the product of the grid dimensions and the threadblock limit:

```
total = (2^31-1)*65535*65535*1024
```

That product is 9,444,444,733,164,249,676,800

Note that on most GPUs, a kernel launch this large, even with an empty kernel, will take a very long time to complete. (*)

The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) covers thread hierarchy as well as how to specify multi-dimensional grids and threadblocks.

(*) For amusement, an empty kernel launch of `<<<dim3(1,65535,65535),1024>>>` takes about 1 minute to process on a GTX960.  So a "maximal" empty kernel launch would take about 2^31 minutes to process (over 4000 years) on that GPU.

Comment: To add extra information to newbies: these are not _simultaneous_ threads. They don't all run at the same time.